# JavaScript regex get number after string

Tags: javascript, regex

After coming to the shocking realization that regular expressions in JavaScript are somewhat different from the ones in PCE, I am stuck with the following.

In php [I extract a number](https://regex101.com/r/eL5bS8/1) **after** x:

```
(?x)[0-9]+
```

In JavaScript the same regex doesn't work, due to *invalid group* resulting from the capturing parenthesis difference.

So I am trying to achieve the same trivial functionality, [but I keep getting](https://www.regex101.com/r/mU8jH7/1) both the x and the number:

```
(?:x)([0-9]+)
```

How do I capture the number **after** x without including x?

Comment: This should work (?!x)([0-9]+).

Comment: @gothical yes it does!

Comment: `(?!x)([0-9]+)` = `([0-9]+)`. And `(?x)[0-9]+` is also equal to `[0-9]+`. To get a sequence of digits after an `x` char in PHP/JS, you can just use `/x(\d+)/` and grab Group 1 value. Or, use a lookbehind, `/(?<=x)\d+/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works too:

`/(?:x)([0-9]+)/.test('YOUR_STRING');`

Then, the value you want is:

`RegExp.$1 // group 1`

Comment: yes that sort of did what I was hoping for:
`var x = str.match(/(?:x)(\d+)/` to match the correct part, and then accessing it with `x[1]`. I'm sure there must be a more elegant way?

Comment: A more elegant way? Dude, I find this beautiful! :D

Comment: Seriously now, the way I wrote it is a very common way of using regex in Javascript.

Comment: I was hoping that I wouldn't have to access an array but a single variable. This approach (which I thank you for) requires that I test the array length. Surely there is a way to do this with the regex? ATM it returns both `x15` and then the second capture group `15`.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the following regex: `(?!x)[0-9]+`

fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/xy6x938e/1/

This is assuming that you are now looking for an x followed by a number, it uses a capture group to capture just the numbers section.

```
var myString = "x12345";
var myRegexp = /x([0-9]+)/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
var myString2 = "z12345";
var match2 = myRegexp.exec(myString2);

if(match != null && match.length > 1){
    alert('match1:' + match[1]);
}
else{
    alert('no match 1');
}
if(match2 != null && match2.length > 1){
    alert('match2:' + match2[1]);
}
else{
    alert('no match 2');
}
```

Comment: actually this is wrong, it will match any number, ignoring whether its x, y or z

Answer (score 2):

(\d+) try this! 
i have tested on this tool with x12345
http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Answer (score 2):

> How do I capture the number after x without including x?

In fact, you just want to *extract* a sequence of digits after a fixed string/known pattern.

Your PCRE (PHP) regex, `(?x)[0-9]+`, is **wrong** becaue `(?x)` is an inline version of a `PCRE_EXTENDED` VERBOSE/COMMENTS flag (see ["Pattern Modifiers"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)). It does not do anything meaningful in this case, `(?x)[0-9]+` is equal to `[0-9]+` or `\d+`.

You can use

```js
console.log("x15 x25".match(/(?<=x)\d+/g));
```

You can also use a *capturing group* and then extract Group 1 value after a match is obtained:

```js
const match = /x(\d+)/.exec("x15");
if (match) {
  console.log(match[1]); // Getting the first match
}

// All matches
const matches = Array.from("x15,x25".matchAll(/x(\d+)/g), x=>x[1]);
console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

You still can use exclusive pattern `(?!...)`

So, for your example it will be `/(?!x)[0-9]+/`. Give a try to the following:

```
/(?!x)\d+/.exec('x123')
// => ["123"]
```

Comment: The problem with this regex (as commented at jimplode's post) is that it matches *any* number following a character, regardless if the key is `x`, `y` or `z`. See for yourself: https://regex101.com/r/oP2eR3/1